# I want to run the timer at 2:00 a.m. and shutdown the application

Tags: c#, .net

I want to run the timer at 2:00 a.m. and shutdown the application.
This is my code:

```
  var ShutdownTimer = new Timer();
  var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

  int hoursUntilShutdown;

  switch (currentTime.Hour)
  {
    case 1:
      hoursUntilShutdown = 1;
      break;

    case 2:
      hoursUntilShutdown = 0;
      break;

    default:
      hoursUntilShutdown = (24 - currentTime.Hour) + 2;
      break;
  }

  var shutdownTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, hoursUntilShutdown, 0, 0);
  ShutdownTimer.Interval = (int)shutdownTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
  ShutdownTimer.Tick += this.OnShutdownTimer;
  ShutdownTimer.Start();

   private void OnShutdownTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Environment.Exit(0);
   }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The whole `switch` can be replaced by `hoursUntilShutdown = (26 - currentTime.Hour) % 24`, where `%` is the remainder of the division, as in C (I don't use C#, so I can only assume it's the same).

Comment: @VedranŠego very good idea please post it as answer I just want vote it. this answer mathematically is better!

Comment: Which 2:00 a.m.? It's one of the more popular times for governments to jiggle around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole `switch` can be replaced by

```
hoursUntilShutdown = (26 - currentTime.Hour) % 24
```

where `%` is the remainder of the division, as in C (I don't use C#, so I can only assume it's the same).